# kendo angular k-ng-delay with ajax data-fetch as the source of data for dataSource

Tags: ajax, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to understand what is meant [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction) by the phrase "when the `gridOptions` variable becomes available".  By "becomes available" is it meant that the kendo UI control is watching or observing the `gridOptions` variable to detect a change?

Also, I don't understand why the $http success-handler creates a new `dataSource` object based on **result.data**, and then in the `gridOptions` object we have `dataSource: data`.  I would expect to see there `dataSource: dataSource`.

Does the dataSource property for the UI widget's ng-delay-configuration object expect to be assigned raw data or a kendo dataSource object?

```
// in controller
$http({ method: "GET", url: "customers.json" })
  .success(function(result){
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: result.data
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      dataSource: data,
      columns: result.columns,
      ...
    };
  });

<!-- in HTML: -->
<div kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-ng-delay="gridOptions"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context "becomes available" means when it is defined in the angular scope the widget will then be created. To rebind the widget when a property changes the `k-rebind` attribute should be used on the widget that you wish to update.

The `$http` success handler is correct in creating a new kendo.data.DataSource, but it should have following code (as you suggested):

```
$http({ method: "GET", url: "customers.json" })
  .success(function(result){
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: result.data
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      dataSource: dataSource,
      columns: result.columns,
      ...
    };
  });
```

Also here the kendo-grid has a `k-rebind` attribute applied, which will refresh the grid when the `gridOptions` item is changed.

```
 <div kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-ng-delay="gridOptions" k-rebind="gridOptions"></div>
```